# Any Way to show Analysis of the Python Code?

Tags: python, analytics, logistic-regression, data-mining, cosine-similarity

So i have this program that gives movie recommendation based on moodby cosine similarity and other categories and it works really well thanks to a github link i found online and worked on it. The problem is that the places where i have kept the cosine similarity , i wanted to shows some kind of analysis ouput from it..maybe accuracy and fmeasure or something since it is a data mining concept.
Below is some if the algorithm code that i wanted to have some sort of anaylsis done, so may i know, if its not too much to ask, how can i get anaylsis or print out analysis from this like accruacy and all. Appreciative if a solution is found and its optional if it shows all the accuracy for the iteration and which one was best that was chosen.

```
#cosine
def find3MostSim(movie_dict, summary_list):# main cosine similarity wth count vectoriser

    # stores each movie's summary
    summary = summary_list[0]

    # the last string in summary is our target for summary similarity analysis
    summary.append(summary_list[1])

    processed = list(map(preprocess, summary))

    # create matrix of unique words
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(processed)
    vectors = vectorizer.toarray()

    # run cosine similarity analysis
    similarity = cosine_similarity(vectors)
    print(similarity)
    # find the 3 most similar movies by their summary adn genre
    target = similarity[-1]
    print(print(targetIndex))
```

Above is cosine similarity function. This full link to the program is on this GitHub https://github.com/vilavivida/MovieMood
Really appreciate if feedback is given and please let me know if my question is vague or too or inappropriate.

I tried to play with the code and did this code print(targetindex) and this output came
[image: This output]
Maybe this may be of some help and i think this must be some accuracy of something.
Thanks

Comment: Please, update the code to show the imports of the packages you are using

Comment: sure..but this is just part of the code..full code can be found at the github link i put there